# Web api - DataAnnotations: optional properties, require the rest if one is present

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, asp.net-web-api2, data-annotations

I am writing a web api application, where i need to deserialize `json` from a `POST request` into a `DTO` that looks like the following

```
public class UserDto
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "User.Email is required")]
    [StringLength(128, ErrorMessage = "The email length cannot exceed 128 characters.")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email         { get; set; } //Always required

    public string UserId        { get; set; }

    public string UserType      { get; set; }
}
```

The rules is as following: `Email` is always required, `UserId/UserType` is optional, but they are linked, as in; if one of the two is present in the `json` the other property is required to be there.

Currently we have this handled in code in our service layer, but i would like to move this into the model, with DataAnnotations, like `[Required]`. This way its validated before it reaches the `controller` and i don't have to make `try/catch` blocks when invoking my service from the `controllers`

The `json format` we accept is as following:

```
{
  "User": {
    "Email": "example@email.com",
    "UserId": "userId", //Optional, but required if 'UserType' is present
    "UserType": "type" //Optional, but required if 'UserId' is present
  }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this with `data annotation`?

Ideally i would like to simply link the two properties together. I was thinking of creating an object for the two properties like `UserData` and have my `json (de)serializer` unwrap the object so we still accept the same format, and only our DTO have to change. (i know this is possible with fx. `jackson` in `java`). But it would be even cooler if it was possible with my current class-structure, with something like `[RequireIf(link = anotherProperty)]` annotation.

Comment: won't it be easier just to create two DTOs?

Comment: If i do that, how will web api / deserializer know which DTO to deserialize to? I have to specify this in my controller method - if i can specify 2 (so it makes a fallback if one deserialization fails) how do i do it? :)

Comment: it seem like you want to merge creating and modifying users (please correct me if I'm wrong) for create use `POST` method, for edit use `PUT` method. `POST` will accept DTO with only `Email`, `PUT` will accept DTO with all three properties.

Comment: Our service just plain out accepts the fact that not all clients will know anything more than email about the user, and that some may know more. But we do require that if you know a userID, you must also know what type of userID it is. With your suggestion i have to force the client to use all 3 properties on `PUT` request (or only 1 on `POST`), which is still untrue.